# How to set rootpw for OpenLDAP using `config` backend?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, openldap

The documentation for `OpenLDAP` set `rootpw` in `slapd.conf` file, however new version OpenLDAP using `config` backend which doesn't use `slapd.conf` any more. So this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a resolution here:

http://www.howtoforge.com/install-and-configure-openldap-on-ubuntu-karmic-koala